# How to implement click event and drag event in HTML Canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I have created a business tool using html canvas.

It contains numerous elements that can be dragged and dropped. I have coded this functionality myself basically saying (pseudocode):

```
if(mouseIsDown && mouseInBoundsOfIcon){
    icon.grabbed = true;
}

if(icon.grabbed){
    icon.x = mouseX;
    icon.y = mouseY;
}
```

Now I would like some of these icons to implement an onClick event as well, making them both clickable and 'drag & droppable'.

The problem is the `mousedown` event gets fired as soon as I click down on a mouse button (obviously). I'm thinking I could use a short timer, when `mousedown` fires and `mouseInBoundsOfIcon==true`, I can start it, when it hits 0.5 seconds for example `icon.grabbed = true`, else if the button is released it counts as a click?

I'm not sure how to go about this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are at least 2 common ways of differentiating between clicks and drag-starts.**

Both these methods involve taking a measurement during mousedown and comparing it to another measurement taken in either mouseup or mousemove.

- Measure the distance the mouse moves. For example, if it moves more than 5 pixels before mouseup it's a drag.
- Measure the time between mousedown and mouseup. For example, if mouseup occurs within 200ms of mousedown, then it's a click.

Helpful Hint: Let mousedown default to `drag-start` rather than `click`. Start dragging on mousedown. If you later determine the user intended a click then put the icon back at its starting position so they don't have slightly nudged icons when intending clicks.